# What is the purpose of using routes in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

```
initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/':(context)=> WelcomeScreen() ,
    '/login':(context) => LoginScreen() ,
    '/register':(context)=>RegistrationScreen(),
  }
```

I am not getting the purpose of using routes, is it just to keep of record in MaterialApp class that where we actually navigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something more easy to use , 
when you want to navigate to a new screen, 
or to a new URL 
Because flutter us using for web also 
Please visit this link for more information

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes